# carry forward of column values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table TableA and TableB. Both has the same columns. I want to update VALUE column value of TableA with VALUE column value of TableB.

Here is my table structure.

**Table A**

```
Date       Value
7/6/2015    0
7/5/2015    0
7/4/2015    0
7/3/2015    0
7/2/2015    0
7/1/2015    100
```

**Table B**

```
Date       Value
7/3/2015    2
7/1/2015    3
```

If VALUE column of TableA does not have any value, then we have to update TableA->VALUE with TableB->VALUE + the least date value(100). Here the least date value of TableA is 100. So I need the value (100 + tableB->VALUE) in TableA.

```
TableA.
Date       Value
7/6/2015    105 Carry forward the last value of this column 
7/5/2015    105 Carry forward the last value of this column 
7/4/2015    105 Carry forward the last value of this column 
7/3/2015    105 103+2(VALUE of TableB)
7/2/2015    103 Carry forward the last value of this column 
7/1/2015    103 (100 +3(VALUE of TableB)
```

Carry forward of the column values based on condition.

Please give me the query asap.

thanks,

Comment: **Please give me the query asap.** ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're after:

```
with tablea as (select to_date('06/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 0 value from dual union all
                select to_date('05/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 0 value from dual union all
                select to_date('04/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 0 value from dual union all
                select to_date('03/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 0 value from dual union all
                select to_date('02/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 0 value from dual union all
                select to_date('01/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 100 value from dual),
     tableb as (select to_date('03/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 value from dual union all
                select to_date('01/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 value from dual)
select ta.dt,
       last_value(decode(ta.value, 0, null, ta.value) ignore nulls) over (order by ta.dt)
         + sum(tb.value) over (order by ta.dt) new_value
from   tablea ta
       left outer join tableb tb on (ta.dt = tb.dt)
order by ta.dt desc;

DT          NEW_VALUE
---------- ----------
06/07/2015        105
05/07/2015        105
04/07/2015        105
03/07/2015        105
02/07/2015        103
01/07/2015        103
```

However, you don't say what happens when there is a non-zero value in A after a series of zero values, it's difficult to say if this will behave how you expect in that situation. E.g., with the same data, but tablea.value = 200 for 4th July:

```
with tablea as (select to_date('06/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 0 value from dual union all
                select to_date('05/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 0 value from dual union all
                select to_date('04/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 0 value from dual union all
                select to_date('03/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 200 value from dual union all
                select to_date('02/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 0 value from dual union all
                select to_date('01/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 100 value from dual),
     tableb as (select to_date('03/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 value from dual union all
                select to_date('01/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 value from dual)
select ta.dt,
       last_value(decode(ta.value, 0, null, ta.value) ignore nulls) over (order by ta.dt)
         + sum(tb.value) over (order by ta.dt) new_value
from   tablea ta
       left outer join tableb tb on (ta.dt = tb.dt)
order by ta.dt desc;

DT          NEW_VALUE
---------- ----------
06/07/2015        205
05/07/2015        205
04/07/2015        205
03/07/2015        105
02/07/2015        103
01/07/2015        103
```

You'll have to update your question to cover all scenarios if my query doesn't do exactly what you're after and you can't work out how to amend it by yourself.